# Why do calls to waveOutGetPosition hang?

Tags: c#, audio, windows-vista

I'm using the `winmm.dll` API method `waveOutGetPosition` to get the current position of the playback of a WAV file.  Sometimes this works as expected for me, but eventually one of the calls never returns and my application locks up.

I found this thread with a few users who have experienced the same problem:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/c6a1e80e-4a18-47e7-af11-56a89f638ad7

but no solution.  Has anyone run into this problem before?

**Update**: I was able to create a sample app that reproduces the problem reliably:

[Problem with waveOutWrite and waveOutGetPosition deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452345/problem-with-waveoutwrite-and-waveoutgetposition-deadlock)

Still haven't fixed it, though.

Comment: If you can reproduce the behavior, I suggest contacting Microsoft Support to file a bug and see if there's a fix available.

Comment: @Mattias: I'll try that if nobody at SO can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a MessageWindow instead of a callback - the MessageWindow allows waveOutGetPosition to return successfully without deadlocking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you lock the call up in its own thread and kill it after a determined amount of time instead of letting it hang your app?  Won't really fix the problem, but it would at least allow you to continue.